# Making netbeans code a little bit shorter

Tags: netbeans, border, jlabel

I am writing a netbeans code and exploring, perchance there is a way to shorten this up where I can call one method to have a mouselistener to every jlabels which changes border color each time mouse enter/exit. The code will be longer if I were to manually input events in each jlabels through r.click>properties>events>mouseEntered and mouseExited.

Here is what I have tried to do at source:

```
private void makeBorderColorsInOneMethod(){
    jLabel2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
            jLabel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.yellow));
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
            jLabel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray));
        }
    });
    jLabel3.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
            jLabel3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.yellow));
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
            jLabel3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray));
        }
    });
    jLabel4.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
            jLabel4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.yellow));
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
            jLabel4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray));
        }
    });
    jLabel5.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
            jLabel5.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.yellow));
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
            jLabel5.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray));
        }
    });
}
```

I want to know if there's any more way to shorten this.